# Convert JSON to Java object SQSEvent

Tags: java, scala, jackson, amazon-sqs, objectmapper

I need to test a method that parses SQS Events, I'd like to be able to convert JSON to SQSEvent to achieve this.

When I tried `ObjectMapper`, I'm getting `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'readValue'` on `tmp.readValue(json, SQSEvent)`

Documentation on SQSEvent class: https://javadoc.io/static/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/2.2.2/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/SQSEvent.html#SQSEvent--

```
  def main(args: String): Unit = {
    val json = "{ \"prop\":\"value\"}"
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

    val sqs = {
      val tmp = new ObjectMapper()
      tmp.readValue(json, SQSEvent)
      tmp
    }

    val test = handleRequest(SQSEvent sqs) //JSON Convert to SQS Event
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass the `SQSEvent` class object to `readValue`. Then things should resolve fine:

```
  def main(args: String): Unit = {
    val json = "{ \"prop\":\"value\"}"
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

    val sqs = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[SQSEvent])

    val test = handleRequest(sqs: SQSEvent) //JSON Convert to SQS Event
  }
```

Comment: Hmm it says `Type Mismatch. Required: SQSEvent, Found: ObjectMapper` for this line:  `val test = handleRequest(sqs)`

Comment: Be careful, in the code you posted above you are assigning the `tmp` variable (of type `ObjectMapper`) to `sqs` rather than the return value of `readValue`.

Comment: Ah scala is strange! Thank you! Changed it to this and it worked `val sqs = {
      val tmp = new ObjectMapper()
      tmp.readValue(json, classOf[SQSEvent])
    }`

Comment: Good to hear, but why use this `tmp` ObjectMapper? You already assigned another one to `mapper`...

Comment: Whooops, I was testing out different approaches and forgot to remove